# Get user location on tap/longpress on the screen mapforge API

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, onlongclicklistener

I would like to get user location when I tap/longpress on the screen using the mapforge API...

this code is not fired even if I longpressed on the screen.

```
     mapView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

     @Override
     public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
     toastLong("onlongclick");
     return false;
     }
     });
```

Comment: how do you initialize your mapView

Answer (score 0):

With  Little Modify

```
mapView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Clicked is working ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: no errors in the logcat.... the code just won't start even if set it to true already

Comment: check the edited answer.. its work fine for me. Hope Same For You also :)

Comment: maybe this will work for google maps api.. but not working for mapforge API

Comment: I Am not confirm about mapForge.. k you can just have a look on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html                                    http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/mapsforge/org/mapsforge/android/maps/MapView.java.htm    Hope This Will Help you